# Excel filter from other list

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, filter

I have 2 lists in excel. First one is for searching (i want to have dropboxes), and second list is for data.
In second list I have filtered data. But what I want to do now is filter from parameters given in first list.

How can I transfer filter headers on first page?

[image: Search list and list with data]

I want to select brand on 'Search' list and results will be filtered on 'Rows' list.

Comment: posting a sample workbook or screen shots of what you are after will go a long way - as of right now, your question is kind of vague

Comment: Well, AFAIK, the only way to do that type of action would be through VBA. Do you know VBA at all. If you do, it would be quite easy with that. I can give you that solution if you want, but perhaps there is a way to do it without VBA. What is your ultimate goal? What will you do with the data once it's filtered? Or why do you need to filter the data? Maybe a non-VBA solution can get you to your end result. add-on -> just a guess, but are you looking to ultimately populate the Model cell with only the relevant choices based on the Brand selected?

Comment: I don't know about VBA, but i guess I'll learn. The point here is just filtere data, nothing more.

Comment: answered below. let me know if it flies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do this exact thing without VBA. Certainly would love to know if there is a way, so maybe someone else can chime in.

That said, here is a small VBA procedure that will get what you want. It works based off a change in the drop down box for Brand in your Search sheet. Follow steps below to implement:

- once in Excel hit Ctrl + F11 on your keyboard. This opens up the VBE
- In the Project - VBAProject window in the upper left click the Object referring to the Search sheet
- Paste the below code into the big window on the right referring to that sheet.
- Make sure to save the file as an .xlsm file (Excel-Macro Enabled File) if using XL2007 or greater.

  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  ```
  Dim wksFilter As Worksheet, wks As Worksheet
  Dim rngFilter As Range

  'replace "A6" with the cell where the Brand dropdown is
  If Target.Address = "$A$6" Then

      Set wks = Sheets(Target.Parent.Name)
      Set wksFilter = Sheets("Rows")

      'may need to adjust the number 1 to match the exact location of your Search Column in the rows sheet
      wksFilter.UsedRange.AutoFilter 1, wks.Range(Target.Address)

  End If
  ```

  End Sub